# Domains not connecting to create drop down list?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, domains

I am trying to create a file geodatabase with features that have drop down list. I have tried going about this by creating a file geodatabase then adding in feature classes by going to new> Feature Class then right clicking the geodatabase hitting properties going to the domain tab and then adding in the code/description. But when I go into the table it does not have the domain listed in properties. I have made sure the domain is labeled the same as the column. I am running ArcGIS 10.6.

Comment: Have you gone to each field's properties and associated your domain with it?

Comment: Make sure the field type matches the domain code type. If they do not match your domain will not show up as an option when trying to assign a domain to the field